# How to display class canvas in a class which does not extend midlet?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

How to display class canvas for menulist in a class not midlet and it's class call in midlet?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you: 1. Reformulate your question (it is really hard to understand), and 2. show what code you have so far. Thank you.

Comment: @JScoobyCed he is right, give proper explanation with your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the class that extends [MIDlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html), obtain an instance of Display object using [getDisplay](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#getDisplay%28javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet%29) API with the instance of MIDlet passed as parameter to that method. Make that *Display* object available where you need to use it (study Java basics if you don't know how to do that)
2. Whenever you need to display a canvas (or any other Displayable object for that matter), use display object mentioned above to invoke [setCurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#setCurrent%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable%29) method with an instance of canvas passed as parameter to that method